# Firefox: Force all caps in Address bar

Tags: javascript, css, firefox

Is it possible to add code (either CSS and/or JavaScript) in userChrome.css to force all uppercase font letters in the Address bar field?

What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: So you want the url to be like `HTTP://STACKOVERFLOW.COM` instead of `http://stackoverflow.com`?

Comment: URLs *are* case-sensitive, so this sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: I just want to know if it's possible to do.  It's a also an easy way to see what website are actually case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking it can be done with CSS.  On this page, it mentions the Location Bar's name is #urlbar
[Chrome Element Names](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Chrome_element_names_and_IDs)

So you should be able to put this CSS in your userChrome.css file:

```
#urlbar{text-transform:uppercase;}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I copy and pasted exactly what you have.  But, it did not change anything after I restarted Firefox.